# What type of class instantiates the factory class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

If i need a factory to create a complex aggregate object, what class instantiates the factory class so to keep my code mockable and testable? A DI container will not be used in this scenario. Some 'type' of class has to bring everything together, no?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no name to it. Whatever your design requires. It can be your Main class, or something downstream (your own DI suite).

Comment: you want the factory to be mockable? use a factory factory. how to mock the factory factory? well, it's pretty simple so just stare at it to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) ultimately brings it all together.